# Why not displaying card

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments

I want to intigrate stripe payment but i got this error
** FlowController must be successfully initialized using configureWithPaymentIntent() or configureWithSetupIntent() before calling presentPaymentOptions()**
How solve this error also it is not displaying any card

```
Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            intpayment(email: "email,amount: 50.0);
            },
          child: Text("Pay20\$"),
        ),
      ),
```

```
Future<void> intpayment(
      {required String email, required double amount})async{
    try{
      final response= await http.post(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents")
          ,body:{
            "receipt_email": email,
            "amount": amount.toInt().toString(),
            "currency": "usd"
          },
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'key',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
      );
      final jsonresponse=jsonDecode(response.body);      Stripe.instance.initPaymentSheet(paymentSheetParameters: SetupPaymentSheetParameters(
        paymentIntentClientSecret: jsonresponse['paymentIntent'],
        merchantDisplayName: 'Zohaib',
      ));
      await Stripe.instance.presentPaymentSheet();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "payment successfully",
      );
    }
    catch(e){
      if (e is StripeException) {
        Fluttertoast.showToast(
            msg: "Stripe error $e",
        );
      }
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: "$e",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, );
    }
  }
```

Comment: Have you setup a Android Side code? we have to change MainActivity.kt
As well in Main function make sure you have added stripe publishable key

Comment: How to change MainActivity.kt?

Comment: https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe
Step -: Installation

Comment: I have change MainActivity.kt but the issue is same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the PaymentIntent on the server-side and not within your flutter app.

```
final response= await http.post(Uri.parse("https://api.stripe.com/v1/payment_intents")
          ,body:{
            "receipt_email": email,
            "amount": amount.toInt().toString(),
            "currency": "usd"
          },
          headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 'key',
            'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
          }
      );
```

Instead of calling the Stripe API directly as you did in the code above, you should call your own API and generate a Payment Intent and just send the `client_secret` to your flutter App, otherwise you would be exposing your secret key and thus giving access to your data. This is described [here](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/docs/sheet.mdx#2-add-an-enpoint-server-side).

Once you do this server-side part the rest is explained [here](https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe/blob/main/docs/sheet.mdx#3-integrate-the-payment-sheet-client-side).